# editableText plugin enabling problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, edit-in-place

I've been experimenting with this plugin http://valums.com/edit-in-place/, so far so good... But i ran into this problem. I want to update my page when update or new request to save data is sent but if i update this function(edit-in-place) it will add second set of buttons, third, fourth and so on. How could i tell it that it would update just on that returned data, but not all elements? I have an idea it has to do something with each function of jquerys, but I'm not sure as I'm quite new to jquery. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe you could give a short (code) example of what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the selector a [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/), so for example if you're doing this now:

```
 $('.editableText').editableText({
    newlinesEnabled: false
 });
```

In your ajax callback, give it a context when calling it in the `success` or `complete` method, wherever you're adding elements, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  ...options here...
  success: function(data) {
    $('.editableText', data).editableText({
      newlinesEnabled: false
    });
    //insert the elements somewhere...
  }
});
```

The `, data` gives it [a context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) ([you can see options for `$(selector, context)` here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)), this means it's only searching for elements of that class **within the returned data/html**, not all elements on the page.  This should eliminate your repetition issue of it selecting and running the plugin on elements it's already run on.